# General Möbius transformation mapping $|z|=r$ onto itself

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find the general form of a Möbius transform that maps the circle $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=r\}$ onto itself.

Comment: Start with $r = 1$, and then scale, I would think. The case $r = 1$ is rather well known, since these are generated by a) the automorphisms of $\mathbb{D}$, b) the inversion $\frac{1}{z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the hint by Daniel Fischer, the transformations end up being 
$$z\mapsto r^2 e^{i\alpha}\frac{z-a}{r^2-\bar a z}\quad \text{and}\quad 
z\mapsto e^{i\alpha}\frac{r^2-\bar a z}{z-a}$$
where $|a|<r$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: and you can combine both of these maps to a single formula.